# image height and width scaling in css

Tags: css

i have been trying to scale images to fit into a div using css. it works fine if the image has equal width ahd height but when the width is greater than the height or vice versa, then the trouble comes in.
this how i did it?

```
#container{
   -webkit-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px; /*makes the div a  nice circle */
   -moz-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    float:left;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}

#picture{
   -webkit-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px; /*makes the image a nice circle*/
   -moz-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please expand on what exactly isnt working

Comment: Do you want to crop your images

Comment: something like cropping. A typical example is that if facebook profile picture

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

That will make the image always either one of those as max.

Comment: this usually stretches the image making making it look like it is altered

Answer (score 0):

By default your browser scales it to fullest to its original size. Set `overflow` property of your `container` id to `hidden` to crop your images.

- For smaller container - use `overflow:hidden;`
- For image sized container - It is something which browser does automatically
- For larger container - You can set `background-repeat` property

---

```
  #container{
       -webkit-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px; /*makes the div a  nice circle */
       -moz-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
        border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
       box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK finally i solved the problem. first i used php to get the height and the width of the image. Then compared both of them.
After that, in my case, if the width is greater than the height, i set the the height to 100% in css and if the height is greater than the width, i set the width to 100%.